# Out of memory error in regex command loop?

Tags: c#, regex

After running a regex, I set the strings to `null` and force garbage collection, but I'm getting an out-of-memory error.

Manual invocations of the garbage collector aren't doing anything. I use `null` for empty strings.

```
int i = 0;

while (i < 40 )
{
    string strFile42 = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\finalregex.txt"); 
    string Value3 = @"\n(.*?)&" ;
    string Value4 =string.Format("\n$1#{0}#", i);
    //Force garbage collection.
    GC.Collect();
    strFile42 = Regex.Replace(strFile42, Value3, Value4);
    //Force garbage collection.
    GC.Collect();

    Value4 = null;
    Value3 = null;
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\finalregex.txt", strFile42);
    strFile42 =null;

    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
    i = i + 1;
}
```

==========================================================

THIS IS MY SOLUTION

```
      string strFile42 =  File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\finalregex.txt");


 \\ regex code for replace (PUT REGEX CODE HERE )


    File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\finalregex.txt", strFile42);


    strFile42 = null ;

  int oldCacheSize = Regex.CacheSize;

Regex.CacheSize         = 0;
  GC.Collect();

    Regex.CacheSize = oldCacheSize; 

  GC.Collect();

 GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```

Comment: Not sure if this is a regex problem, but `\n(.*?)&` also removes the newline it matches.

Comment: the code works but stop after 20 seg because the memory is enough

Comment: @zero625 replacement looks fine. Did you try to debug your code? Are you sure the problem is not about infinite while loop? Try to format your code and insert the whole method

Comment: @zero625 also try not to use GC in your code. It works well by itself. Try to follow some naming convensions of c# world so people will more likely try to help you

Comment: my code works this stop when i < 40 not infinite the problem is the memory this sum 70mb of memory per loop and  stop at 2gb

Comment: i try to clean the memory  per loop

Comment: You don't need the first two GC, just clean it once per loop pass, and at the end. And `WaitForPendingFinalizers` has got that _wait_ word in it.

Comment: I try but not work

Comment: What is the size of this file ? C:\Users\diego\Desktop\finalregex.txt

Comment: Does it break at this line ?     strFile42 = Regex.Replace(strFile42, Value3, Value4);

Comment: yes this break . how i can solve? , please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm wondering if the cashSize of the Regex isn't the problem.

In the MSDN information, there is a page on [Regex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Quote:

> The Regex class maintains an internal cache of compiled regular expressions used in static method calls. If the value specified in a set operation is less than the current cache size, cache entries are discarded until the cache size is equal to the specified value.
>   By default, the cache holds 15 compiled static regular expressions. Your application typically will not have to modify the size of the cache. Use the CacheSize property only when you want to turn off caching or when you have an unusually large cache.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12957612/3666410) is a question about CashSize of Regex

Comment: hi friend how i can do this ,  I dont know

Comment: i use this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c93474ae-ad03-4c9b-ae7d-a6bbb6adb033/regexreplace-memory-leak?forum=regexp

Comment: I don't see how the regex cache can be the problem.  The code in the question only uses one regex, so the cache size will never get larger than 1.

Comment: @zero625 all credits for you. You finnaly found the answer. Can you edit your question with your solution? This can be handy for other people.

Answer (score 5):

You allocate huge size for string when you use:
     string strFile42 = File.ReadAllText(filename);
and doing  Regex.Replace on all that huge size at a time represent overhead on memory.

Strings are allocated on the large object heap, which are not collected by GC with other small objects. 
 When you call GC.Collect() to revoke garbage collector, GC **CANNOT** guarantee the string will be collected immediately.

So, it is best to use BufferedStream  with StreamReader and handle one line at a time ,without any overhead on memory.

I measured memory used within execution to monitor memory allocation.

The following class can handle  huge size of file without any problems

```
  public void FileProcess()
    {
        Process proc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 40)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" i: {0} - Private memory: {1} KB- Memory Used: {2} KB", i,
                proc.PrivateMemorySize64/1024.0, GC.GetTotalMemory(true)/1024.0);    
            var path = "test0.txt";
            var path2 = "test2.txt";
            using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs))
            using (StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(path2))
            {
                string line;
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {

                    var text = ProcessLine(line, i);
                    outputFile.WriteLine(text);
                }
            }
            i++;
            // Collect all generations of memory.
            // GC.Collect(); //you need not

        } //while
    }

    private string ProcessLine(string text, int i)
    {
        string Value3 = @"(.*?)&";
        string Value4 = string.Format("$1#{0}#", i);
        var strFile42 = Regex.Replace(text, Value3, Value4);
        return strFile42;
    }
}
```

**Bench Mark Performance Test:**

I Generated file with strings with size 72 MB, and used the class to process the file 40 times without any overhead at all.
As you see the memory used by application is about 252K and constant all the time without GC collection.

results

```
     i: 0 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 251.8828125 KB
     i: 1 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.5390625 KB
     i: 2 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.5390625 KB
     i: 3 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.5390625 KB
     i: 4 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.5390625 KB
     i: 5 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.5390625 KB
     i: 6 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.5390625 KB
     i: 7 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 8 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 9 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 10 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 11 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 12 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 13 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 14 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 15 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 16 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 17 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 18 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 19 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 20 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 21 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 22 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 23 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 24 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 25 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 26 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 27 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 28 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 29 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 30 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 31 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 32 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 33 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 34 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 35 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 36 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 37 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 38 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
     i: 39 - Private memory: 18212 KB- Memory Used: 274.48828125 KB
```

Answer (score 1):

I post my answer here

I use this code for clean memory leak

```
        string strFile42 =  File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\finalregex.txt");


  \\ regex code for replace (PUT REGEX CODE HERE )


     File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Users\diego\Desktop\finalregex.txt", strFile42);


      strFile42 = null ;

   int oldCacheSize = Regex.CacheSize;

  Regex.CacheSize         = 0;
   GC.Collect();

        Regex.CacheSize = oldCacheSize; 

    GC.Collect();

GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
```